# Linux / Django / Site not reachable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, django

Something wrong. 2 months ago I was able to access my django server to this url/port

```
http://212.47.245.79:8000/
```

Yesterday I went back to this machine, as connection was down. I have restarted django, and I got *ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* in my browser

With `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` I can see the port 8000 is in LISTEN mode.

What could be the cause ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of `wget http://212.47.245.79:8000/` (from the same server)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RomeoNinov with your  command : `connecting to 212.47.245.79:8000... failed: connection refused`

Comment: @fransua, check if you have firewall activated on this system

Comment: `ufw status` -> Status: inactive

Comment: Can you post the output of netstat -nlp | grep 8000? Maybe it's listening on a wrong interface or only on localhost.

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      260163/python

Answer (score 1):

Judging from netstat output you provided, the process is listening on localhost interface only:

```
tcp 0 0 >>127.0.0.1:8000<< 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 260163/python
```

It means that you'll be able to connect to the port locally but any external connection will result in "Connection refused".

It's really hard to answer why it happened, possibly a configuration change or maybe some update messed things up. You need to review your configuration and make sure the process is listening on '0.0.0.0:8000' or maybe just one specific interface.

For example launching in CLI like this will cause listening on localhost only:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

To make it listen on all interfaces you would need to launch it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Hope this helps.